# Synchronizing GitHub public repo and Gitea private repo superset

Tags: github, synchronization, gitea

We publish on github an open project package that includes a software application and canonical inputs. We use the software ourselves, developing alternate inputs and scripts that are considered private or experimental -- some will ideally get published publicly, others won't but still need to be archived.

We would like to keep a repo (mirror, fork, not sure of the vocabulary) in our local gitea server. 
1. Ideally, we could synchronize the public subset of the material (at least master) regularly from GitHub to gitea. 
2. Our work would be on branches that at most are dead end efforts updated one way from master to branch. 
3. Occasionally, we come up with improvements in the core approach, so it would help if we could cherry-pick those from the project branch to github possibly with Gitea master as the intermediary.

How is this done? It isn't clear that server concepts like "fork" span the two environments, Gitea and GitHub, and most of what I've read goes private-to-public and involves GitLab and I'm not sure if I can identify the subset to automate. Assuming it can be done reasoably, is my recourse to have a local repository that treats them as peers and acts as an intermediary? Perhaps with chron jobs or equivalent windows tools? What is the state of the art?

Answer (score 0):

> It isn't clear that server concepts like "fork" span the two environments

It does not exactly, considering GitHub forks are for facilitating contributions back to the original repository, through Pull Request.

In your case, it would be more of a mirror, for a specific repository.

You can consider [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), like [`spyoungtech/mirror-action`](https://github.com/spyoungtech/mirror-action) to automate replication from one environment (GitHub, when pushing new commits) to another (Gitea)